# format has different behavior for seemingly identical lists

Tags: python, string, list, formatting, sympy

I have the following python commands :

```
>>> list([0, 1])
[0, 1]
>>> list(myobject)
[0, 1]
>>> print(['{:.2f}'.format(val) for val in list([0, 1])])
['0.00', '1.00']
>>> print(['{:.2f}'.format(val) for val in list(myobject)])
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

Why is it that though both `list([0, 1])` and `list(myobject)` return the same list `[0, 1]`, formating one works while formating the other doesn't?

If it helps, the `myobject` in question is a `sympy.geometry.Point`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the values *in* the list print the same way doesn't mean they can be formatted the same way. `sympy.geometry.Point` contain [`sympy.core.number.*` objects](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.numbers), not Python numbers:

```
>>> from sympy import Point3D
>>> myobject = Point3D(1, 2, 2)
>>> type(myobject.x)
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.One'>
```

This will work:

```
>>> print(['{!r}.00'.format(val) for val in myobject])
```

because then you apply `repr()` on each value in `myobject` first. The following will work too, but then a standard formatting for arbitrary objects is applied:

```
>>> print(['{}.00'.format(val) for val in myobject])
```

(I removed the `list()` call in both examples as it is redundant here).

The values yielded by `myobject` probably have a custom `__repr__` method, that returns the value as a string digit. What they are lacking is a custom `__format__` method, and the default `object.__format__` that is then inherited refuses to accept formatting parameters.

To actually format the objects as floats, convert them first:

```
print(['{:.2f}'.format(float(val)) for val in myobject])
```

Demo:

```
>>> print(['{!r}.00'.format(val) for val in myobject])
['1.00', '2.00', '2.00']
>>> print(['{}.00'.format(val) for val in myobject])
['1.00', '2.00', '2.00']
>>> print(['{:.2f}'.format(float(val)) for val in myobject])
['1.00', '2.00', '2.00']
```

Comment: thanks a lot!  I ended up using `'{:.2f}'.format(val) for val in list(vertex.evalf())` since I wanted the decimal form (I was so close!)